# PHP / Laravel : Retrieve new info of Model after save()

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, orm

Here's my issue : I have a table in sqlserver database as follow :

```
Product ( 
 id int identity,
 reference varchar(12),
 name varchar(40)
)
```

In a web page of a laravel web-app, I got a form with name only as field and a submit button. 
In DB side, I created a trigger (Instead of insert) that updates the reference of the row based on the generated id.
Example :

```
RGX0000123
```

Where 123 is the generated ID and RGX is randomly generated.

The flow follows Post/Redirect/Get design pattern. After the submit, I want to redirect to a page where the reference is shown in the URL and not the ID.

In laravel's controller, I save my object with Eloquent and redirect to the next page :

```
$product->save();
return redirect()->route('next_page', ['reference' => $product->reference]);
```

My problem is that I can get the id after the save but not the reference. I don't know how Eloquent works but with Hibernate(JAVA) such thing can be resolved with a session.flush() to sync the object with data from the database.

Quick and dirty fix was using

```
$product= Product::find($product->id);
```

Is there a cleaner way to handle this ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Refresh the object instead:

```
$product->save();
$product->refresh(); // <---

return redirect()->route('next_page', ['reference' => $product->reference]);
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#retrieving-models):

> #### Refreshing Models
>
> You can refresh models using the `fresh` and `refresh` methods. The
> `fresh` method will re-retrieve the model from the database. The
> existing model instance will not be affected:
>
> ```
> $flight = App\Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
>
> $freshFlight = $flight->fresh();
> ```
>
> The `refresh` method will re-hydrate the existing model using fresh
> data from the database. In addition, all of its loaded relationships
> will be refreshed as well:
>
> ```
> $flight = App\Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
>
> $flight->number = 'FR 456';
>
> $flight->refresh();
>
> $flight->number; // "FR 900"
> ```

Comment: That did  the job. Thanks

Comment: I have a uuid column (not a primary key) that is created upon database insert. refresh was not bringing this field into my model, but fresh did

Answer (score 1):

You can use refresh() method for refresh data in model

> $model->refresh();